# My accociated account rep is MIA

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

I created accounts on both sports.SE and Mathematics after passing 200 reputation on gaming.SE in order to get the reputation I am due. However, it has been 12 hours and the +100 reputation on either gaming.SE, sports.SE, or Mathematics is nowhere to be found. As an experiment, I wrote an answer on sports.SE to see if that would trigger the bonus rep, but it did not. I hear that there have been problems with this recently but that they have been fixed. However, I am experiencing the same issues. I used the same openid to login to all accounts, and the other accounts are registering under my profile. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: There was a bug this week, which prevented the system from giving you the bonus rep. Apparently it hasn't been fixed yet, but the devs are already aware of the problem AFAIK

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. Any idea when it will be fixed?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125439/just-created-an-account-on-a-new-se-site-wheres-my-100-rep It should be fixed, but I can't give you any more info about it

Comment: OK. Thanks, just wanted to make this problem known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association bonus has been found and awarded. :)

Comment: OK Thank you! Will this problem happen for other new users in the future? Is this still a bug?

Comment: @Portali5t It was a bug (a missed edge case on the issue Ivo linked to in the comments above, to be precise), but it should be fixed now.

Comment: OK, thank you for clarifying.